# Google analytics and different domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I asked this question directly to the Google Analytics community with absolutely no answer.

The question is as follow:

I have a AI based site, which give a customer a specific aid to select the right product he/she want to buy. The front ed application is React/js based.

My site is usually a small icon on a merchant site, and the user, while he/she is navigating the merchant site, can decide to recall clicking on a specific icon.

Then my site opens and help the user to select the right product(s) belonging to the merchant site. The product are choosen and then clicked to be added to the merchant cart.

Of course, there is a written agreement between the merchant and I to be signed, and some changes to the merchant site to incorporate my clickable icon: I'd like to pass a piece of code to the merchant including the icon and all the code needed to implement this kind of application.

So, given that the merchant call my site passing a specific transaction related token and the customer info (if any) when the user click on my icon, how can I:

- directly add one or more items into the merchant cart
- track the action made by the user after he/she leave me site and return to the  merchant one to conclude the journey with a payment, so I can later invoice the merchant for the right commission
- track if the user remove some (or all  the) item from the cart, so I have less to nothing commissions to invoice.

I tried to follow the instruction given by google, but they are a mess, and I wasn't able to reach any conclusion.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Adding items to the merchant's cart is possible using some live API that the client would extend, but the easiest way to do it would be just using the window.postMessage(). So, I would suggest having your button implemented as a simple iframe. That will make it possible for you to send messages to the parent page from that button. The parent page, however, has to be ready to listen to those messages and add to cart whatever ids you specify. So the client devs will have to do some implementation for this to work.
2. Well, no, this is a bit too much to ask for. You can ask the merchant to share that data with you so that you could improve your algos (tune them for the client) and, therefore, improve the merchant's conversion rates (which is a win-win scenario), but the merchant would have to actively either implement parallel tracking to your instance of analytics (install your pixel, if you're willing to develop one), or share their own data with you.

That's what a lot of very similar services do. Let's say, Facebook. Facebook sells traffic. When you buy traffic, you generally don't want to pay for irrelevant/badly converting tracking, so you're implementing so-called facebook pixel. Facebook doesn't do this implementation. Client's developers/implementation experts implement it and trigger various events through it, making it send signals to the FB endoint, indicating which client this is from, for which campaign, what the action is page load, purchase, add to cart... Just take a quick glance at FB documentation: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/402791146561655?id=1205376682832142

Facebook is just an example. There are many-many services that do similar pixels. It may be not about selling traffic, it may be about adjusting site look and feel based on AI, or generating discounts and customizing conversion funnels, or even simpler stuff like feedback chat performance and suggestions modules. All these and more exist as third parties and pretty much all of the established ones use pixels for tracking.

If you don't want to spend time at the moment to make your own tracking logic, then implementing a parallel GA tracking will be a pain for you (for your clients, actually). Instead, it would be easier to enrich their data with your products. Let's say, have them implement a product-level custom dimension that would "paint" products added to cart by you and share the data with you.

Note that a client who goes for it must be a very loyal client since analytics data is normally treated as sensitive and is not readily shared with third parties, not mentioning the implementation of a custom dimension (or the using the expensive product parameters) just for a third party to count their conversions. Yes, it has to be a good friend that allows this.

Finally, you could ask them installing your GTM instance or giving you access to theirs, but that would effectively give you the power to execute arbitrary code on any of their page. I would never give a third party that power.

Tl;Dr: I would suggest making your own very simple pixel. Even though it sounds now like a lot of work, it will worth it if the project itself has real potential to be useful for ecommerce.

3. Exactly the same as 2.

Comment: Thank you @BNazaruk. This is not a good notice, or, at least, is not the one I hoped to receive. But, to be honest, the limits you describe are the same I imagined to be face with. No miracle on the way!